# Rotate text to face user when camera is rotated

Tags: three.js

If you take a look at my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jmg157/Y35cQ/1/

You'll see I have grid labels on the cube axes.  What I'd like to do is whenever the user rotates around the cube, have the text rotate as well so that the numbers are always facing the user.

I tried things like `xMarks.rotation = camera.rotation`, where `xMarks`are the text objects, but no success.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

three.js is now quaternion-based.

To make the text created with `THREE.PlaneGeometry` face the camera, do this:

```
mesh.quaternion = camera.quaternion; // EDIT - see note below
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y35cQ/2/

An alternative is to use `THREE.Sprite`, which always faces the camera.

three.js r.63

---

EDIT - `mesh.quaternion = camera.quaternion;` no longer works. You must use this pattern instead:

```
mesh.quaternion.copy( camera.quaternion );
```

three.js r.67