# Three.js make the text created with THREE.ShapeGeometry face the camera

Tags: three.js

I created a shapegeometry with the text. How can I keep the text face the camera on move the camera?

```
...

this.textGeometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(THREE.FontUtils.generateShapes(value, parameters));
this.textValue = new THREE.Mesh(this.textGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: color, side: THREE.DoubleSide }));
this.textValue.matrixAutoUpdate = true;
this.add(this.textValue)

...
```

I think my problem is that I modified the parent quaternion 3D object:

```
this.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle (axis, radians);
```

then the only operation:

```
textValue.quaternion.copy (camera.quaternion);
```

is not sufficient

how can I fix the rotation considering the state of the quaternion?

Comment: this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470516/rotate-text-to-face-user-when-camera-is-rotated did not help you?

Comment: No, because I have a shapegeometry

Comment: Try `textValue.quaternion.copy( camera.quaternion );` `textValue's` parent should be the scene, or at least a non-rotated object.

Comment: ok, I think my problem is that the parent object is itself an object rotated, with your solution the text rotates, but it is not correct. How do I correct rotation?

Comment: The only solution is to satisfy the parental requirements I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about calling the base updateMatrix function, 
this can be a solution

```
yourShapeGeometry.prototype.updateMatrix = function(){
 // THREE.Object3D.prototype.updateMatrix.call(this);
 fixOrientation(this.textValue); 
}

function fixOrientation(mesh){
  mesh.setRotationFromQuaternion(camera.quaternion);
  mesh.updateMatrix();
}
```

or simply edit the updateMatrix of your text mesh like

```
textMesh.updateMatrixWorld = updateSpriteWorld;
function updateSpriteWorld(){

        if ( this.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate === true || force === true ) {

                this.setRotationFromQuaternion(camera.quaternion);
                this.updateMatrix();
                this.matrixWorld.copy( this.matrix );
                this.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = false;

                force = true;
        }

        // update children

        for ( var i = 0, l = this.children.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

            this.children[ i ].updateSpriteWorld( force );

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

```
this.textValue.lookAt( camera.position );
```

Comment: `lookAt()` does not support objects with rotated and/or translated parent(s), which is the OP's situation, apparently.

Comment: also, when doing this sprite like camera alignment, this wont actually make it parallel? You need to be looking at the closest point belonging to a plane, parallel to the cameras far and near, not the camera?

Comment: @pailhead It is an approximation. The perspective projection causes some distortion anyway.

Comment: it does but it's one thing if a plane is parallel to the projection plane, another if it's at an angle?